# Scala get the last word when certain word present in string

Tags: string, scala

I have this list. How can I extract [Chickpeas,SweetPotatoes]?

I need to search for plugins and get the last word in the url.

```
"https://apple.com/adm/context/events/AllEvents",
"https://apple.com/adm/plugins/common/SweetPotatoes"
"https://apple.com/adm/plugins/common/Cheakpeas"
```

My try is like this. I want something more elegant.

```
var lst= List[String]()
for (url <- allUrls) {
  if (a.contains("plugins")) {
    lst ::= a.split("/").last.replace(""""""","")
  }
}
print(lst)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Another option you have is:

```
allUrls.filter(u => u.contains("plugins")).map(_.split('/').last)
```

Code run at [Scastie](https://scastie.scala-lang.org/toshetah/BQRJz9f0QhuYfGZjMKZ5qA/1).

Or:

```
allUrls.collect { case u if u.contains("plugins") => u.split('/').last }
```

Code run at [Scastie](https://scastie.scala-lang.org/toshetah/BQRJz9f0QhuYfGZjMKZ5qA/2).

Answer (score 3):

Try a regex pattern.

```
val pluginsRE = ".*/plugins/.*/([^/]+)".r
allUrls.collect{case pluginsRE(s) => s}
//res0: List[String] = List(SweetPotatoes, Cheakpeas)
```

In this case the pattern expects a gap between `"plugins"` part and the target string. That can be adjusted as required.

Answer (score 1):

You wanna run a loop starting at the end and build a string and stop when you reach a "/"

Consider a variable

```
url = s://apple.com/adm/plugins/common/SweetPotatoes"
```

Psuedo Code:

(Assuming you already did the .contains(plug-in) check)

```
Result = ""
Index = url.length-1
while (url[index] != "/")
Result += url[index--]
Return Result
```

Answer (score 1):

assuming that you have the original input in a list, you can do ,

```
import java.net.URI
import java.nio.file.Paths

val urls: List[String] = List("https://apple.com/adm/plugins/common/Cheakpeas",
  "https://apple.com/adm/context/events/AllEvents",
  "https://apple.com/adm/plugins/common/SweetPotatoes")

val pluginList: Seq[String] =
  urls.filter(u => u.contains("plugins")).
    map(u => Paths.get(new URI(u).getPath).getFileName.toString)
```